# Redirect rule not working for https://example.com to https://www.example.com

Tags: redirect, web-config

I want to redirect web url from https://example.com to https://www.example.com.

```
<rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{SERVER_PORT}" pattern="443" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.konstdatabasen.se/{R:1}" redirectType="Found" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that your condition is matching the right URL. Try this:

```xml
<rule name="RedirectNonWwwToWww" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^konstdatabasen.se$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.konstdatabasen.se/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Source: [Web.config redirects with rewrite rules - https, www, and more](https://blog.elmah.io/web-config-redirects-with-rewrite-rules-https-www-and-more/#redirect-non-www-to-www)